# iterm2's drop-down auto command complete doesn't work on remote sessions

Tags: command-line, ssh, remote, autocomplete, iterm2

On remote hosts via ssh the **cmd + ;** command works in displaying part of the suggested command but the "Auto Command Completion" feature doesn't. How can I make the shown feature here work on remote hosts?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after setting up shell integration on remote host. This is done by following the instructions here:
https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html